# How do I uninstall a package installed using npm link?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-link

When installing a node package using `sudo npm link` in the package's directory, how can I uninstall the package once I'm done with development?

`npm link` installs the package as a symbolic link in the system's global package location ('/usr/local/lib`). This allows you to test the package while still developing it, without having to install it over and over again.

Which npm command do I need to run to remove the link again?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

The package can be uninstalled using the same *uninstall* or *rm* command that can be used for removing installed packages. The only thing to keep in mind is that the link needs to be uninstalled globally - the `--global` flag needs to be provided.

In order to uninstall the globally linked `foo` package, the following command can be used (using `sudo` if necessary, depending on your setup and permissions)

```
sudo npm rm --global foo
```

This will uninstall the package.

To check whether a package is installed, the `npm ls` command can be used:

```
npm ls --global foo
```

Comment: If you aren't sure the name of the linked package you can also do `npm ls --global --depth 0` to list all your top level dependencies

Comment: This didn't work for me because of permission issues, even with `sudo`. I created the missing directory with a dummy `package.json` with the `name` and `version` field (`name` should match the package name, `version` can be anything). Inside that folder I ran `npm link && npm unlink` and it worked.

Comment: `npm uninstall` from the local library folder will also work.

Comment: `sudo` isn't necessary if you're using something like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to install node

Comment: `npm list -g --depth=1` worked for me

Comment: With latest version of node you should use: `npm rm --location=global foo`

Answer (score 182):

you can use `unlink` to remove the symlink.

*For Example:*

```
cd ~/projects/node-redis 
npm link                 
cd ~/projects/node-bloggy
npm link redis             # links to your local redis
```

To reinstall from your package.json:

```
npm unlink redis
npm install
```

https://www.tachyonstemplates.com/npm-cheat-sheet/#unlinking-a-npm-package-from-an-application

Comment: Isn't `unlink` the same as `rm` for `npm`? They share the same man page (with `uninstall`).

Comment: @nwinkler can you share a link?

Comment: The npm source code uses rm, unlink, remove, r and un as aliases for uninstall: https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/a964fe1a3bf3fb617c396fe508c531f6dfcc628f/lib/npm.js#L69 - see line 66ff.

Comment: The link at the bottom of this answer is dead for me.

Comment: Doesn't `npm i` remove all links anyway?

Comment: Doing `npm unlink` and `npm install` does not work

Comment: `npm unlink` deleted my package

Answer (score 32):

## npm link pain:

-Module name **gulp-task**

-Project name **project-x**

---

You want to link **gulp-task**:

1: Go to the gulp-task directory then do `npm link` this will symlink the project to your global modules

2: Go to your project **project-x** then do `npm install` make sure to remove the current node_modules directory

---

Now you want to remove this madness and use the real **gulp-task**, we have two options:

#### Option 1: Unlink via npm:

1: Go to your project and do `npm unlink gulp-task` this will remove the linked installed module

2: Go to the **gulp-task** directory and do `npm unlink` to remove symlink. **Notice we didn't use the name of the module**

3: celebrate

---

What if this didn't work, verify by locating your global installed module. My are location `ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules/` if you are using **nvm** it will be a different path

---

#### Option 2: Remove the symlink like a normal linux guru

1: locate your global dependencies `cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

2: removing symlink is simply using the `rm` command

`rm gulp-task` **make sure you don't have `/` at the end**

`rm gulp-task/` **is wrong**

`rm gulp-task` ✔️

Comment: doing a plain `npm-unlink` removed *all* packages in my project.

Comment: @cst1992 what you did is the same as `npm uninstall`

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

1. check the list of npm global packages:

   **npm ls --global**
2. uninstall your package:

   **npm uninstall --global my-package**
3. go to your testbed and unlink the linked package:

   **npm unlink my-package**
4. navigate to your testbed directory and reinstall packages:

   **npm install**
5. restart your testbed server

Comment: Very clear and concise!

Answer (score 6):

`npm uninstall --global my-package`

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can undo the `link` command with the `unlink` command.

#### Create a link

In package

```
cd ./some-package
npm link
```

In comsumer

```
cd ./some-project 
npm link some-package
```

### Remove a link

Removing a link should be done in the reverse order - start from the consumers.

```
cd ./some-project 
npm unlink some-package
```

In package

```
cd ./some-package
npm unlink
```

Comment: If you used link to override an existing package this will leave you without the published version of the package.
You need to do `npm unlink some-package && npm install some-package`. Even then you'll still need to remove the global package with `npm rm --global some-package`

Answer (score 1):

If you've done something like accidentally `npm link` generator-webapp after you've changed it, you can fix it by cloning the right generator and linking *that*.

```
git clone https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp.git;
# for fixing generator-webapp, replace with your required repository
cd generator-webapp;
npm link;
```

Answer (score 1):

"npm install" replaces all dependencies in your node_modules installed with "npm link" with versions from npmjs (specified in your package.json)

Comment: The OP asked about how to uninstall packages installed with `npm link` not `npm link somepackage`. what you suggest would leave the package at the global node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

So many answers, yet none of them consider the case where someone would want to *keep* a package with the same name in `package.json`.

The correct workflow for the case where you want to keep `my-linked-module` in `package.json` after unlinking:

First follow the usual steps for `npm link`, I won't write them all here.

Then:

```bash
npm link my-linked-module
# do some work with the linked module

# time to unlink, but KEEP package.json unchanged
npm unlink my-linked-module --no-save
# and then need to install to get the old unlinked version back
npm install
```

Tested with npm 9.5.1

Answer (score 0):

---

1. stop running dev environment in your project using the npm package
2. use `npm unlink package`
3. from node_modules remove .package-lock.json
4. npm install package or link
5. run dev again

---