# How do I force Yarn to reinstall a package?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

My project has a dependency that I sometimes get from a package server and sometimes get from a local copy I have on my machine. As a result, I frequently need to have Yarn switch where it looks for the dependency. Furthermore, I often change the local copy of the dependency and need to see that change reflected in my main project. As a result, I need a way to tell Yarn to continue looking at the same location for the dependency, but to reinstall the dependency, skipping the cache and grabbing it directly from its current source, even when the version number hasn't changed. (Sometimes I want try small changes to the dependency, and updating the version number every time would quickly become annoying.)

How do I do so?

I've tried the following, but none of them work:

```
yarn remove dependency
yarn add file:/dependency
```

Continues to use the previous version of the dependency.

```
yarn remove dependency
yarn cache clear
yarn add file:/dependency
yarn install --force
```

Also continues to use the previous version of the dependency.

```
yarn remove dependency
rm -rf node_modules/
yarn cache clear
yarn add file:/dependency
yarn install --force
```

Still continues to use the previous version of the dependency.

How can I ensure that Yarn is using the latest version of my dependency?

Comment: I had this conversation in chat about this question: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/reinstalling-local-dependency-in-yarn The advice I got in this chat sometimes works, but I have a hard time consistently updating my local dependency.

Comment: Remove your node_modules directory, update your package.json with the proper version, and reinstall everything. Yarn is fast; it'll only take you a few seconds.

Comment: @EzraChang As I discussed in my question, I've tried that and it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the [`yarn link` command](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link). This will set up your local dependency so that whenever you make a change on the dependency, it immediately shows up in your main project without you having to do anything else to update it.

If your main project is in `~/programming/main` and your dependency is in `~/programming/dependency` and is named `MyLocalDependency`, you will want to:

1) Run `yarn link` (with no additional flags) from within your dependency:

```
cd ~/programming/dependency
yarn link
```

2) Run `yarn link <name of dependency package>` from within your main project:

```
cd ~/programming/main
yarn link MyLocalDependency
```

And you're done!

If you want to switch from a local copy of the dependency to one hosted elsewhere, you can use [`yarn unlink`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/unlink).

```
cd ~/programming/main
yarn unlink MyLocalDependency
cd ~/programming/dependency
yarn unlink
```

---

If you're using NPM instead of Yarn, `npm link` and `npm link <dependency>` work in effectively the same way. To unlink the dependency, run `npm rm --global <dependency>`. (This is because `npm link` works by creating a simlink in the global NPM set of packages, so uninstalling the linked dependency from the global packages also breaks the link.)

See [the `npm link` documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) and  [How do I uninstall a package installed using npm link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094630/how-do-i-uninstall-a-package-installed-using-npm-link)

Answer (score 203):

Reinstalling a package after just deleting the node module works with:

`yarn install --check-files`

Comment: It doesn't when the source is a git repo

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...usually the source is a git repo and it works.

Comment: @abimelex I think Jaime means a reference in package.json like this: `"dependencies" : { "project" : "user/project#branch-name" }`.

Comment: This fixed my "Error: Cannot find module '../lib/completion'" and similar issues prob caused by mega sync! Thank you!

Comment: For Yarn 2, I thought the equivalent command might be `yarn install --check-cache`, but it seems to not be, since it didn't work to force a package reinstall (for the ones I tested anyway). For now, I'm using the workaround of changing the dependency's version in `package.json`, running `yarn`, then changing it back, and running `yarn` again.

Comment: can anyone tell what the solution for this is in yarn 3 with pnp instead of node modules ?

Comment: It took a bit to re-install the one package I deleted from modules. I assume --check-files checks all the folders.

Answer (score 44):

There is one other way.
Just use `yarn upgrade package-name`

See manual: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/

Comment: This may have unintended effects as it will update the package to the latest version within the range specified in package.json.

Comment: If you want to just update the existing package with it's existing version, this won't work.

Answer (score 34):

As [Kevin self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879331/858602), `yarn link` is a good option.
But it can cause some issues if the package you are linking has *peer* dependencies.

What [Karl Adler said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46581747/858602) is also a way to go:

```
yarn --check-files
```

But this will reinstall (`yarn` without sub-command is the same as `yarn install`) every package which has changed.

So, if you really want to just reinstall one package:

```
yarn add package-name --force
```

Comment: command `yarn --check-files --force ` solved for me issue.

Answer (score 17):

Beside these answers, I have a problem with switching git branches and the `yarn`. I have a branch for updating `node_modules` packages and another one for my project bug fixing. when I checkout the bug fix and back to updating branch, `yarn install` or `yarn` returns:

```
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.79s.
```

But all new packages are not installed. so with the below command, I forced yarn to install all packages:

```
yarn --check-files
```

And now it returns:

```
  Building fresh packages...
✨  Done in 79.91s.
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

1. [yarn cache clean [<module_name...>]](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/cache/#toc-yarn-cache-clean)
2. yarn add [<module_name...>]

Answer (score 4):

Although this isn't a Yarn answer (it does seem to work fine with yarn, no package.lock or anything), this is what I ended up doing for cypress (cypress puts files where imho, it shouldn't, and if you're caching node_modules in CI... Leaving this answer in case someone else has a similar problem to me, and finds this post.

```
npm rebuild cypress
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you were like me and were installing one of your personal packages (no one else had access) that you rebased and then force pushed to git, and received the error:

```
$ yarn add https://github.com/username/my-rebased-package.git
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: pull
Directory: /Users/eric/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/.tmp/8ebab1a3de712aa3968f3de5d312545b
Output:
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

You can solve this by just directly removing the cached folder:

```
$rm -rf /Users/eric/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/.tmp/8ebab1a3de712aa3968f3de5d312545b
```

You can then install no problem.