# How to delete a

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I created an `npm link` inside a local dependency. I've since deleted that local dependency off my HDD.

Now I'm trying to delete this `npm link`.

I've tried:

- `npm rm --global dependency`
- `npm uninstall dependency`
- `npm unlink --no-save dependency`

However, after doing all that, and after the code has been deleted from my HDD, `npm link dependency` *still* works when called from my main project. How to delete it properly? Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack serve",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "d3-array": "^3.0.1",
    "d3-dsv": "^3.0.1",
    "d3-format": "^3.0.1",
    "d3-scale": "^4.0.0",
    "d3-time-format": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3-array": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/d3-dsv": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/d3-format": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/d3-scale": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/d3-time-format": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your package.json ?

Weird, this should works

```
npm unlink dependency
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

It was asked here [How do I uninstall a package installed using npm link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094630/how-do-i-uninstall-a-package-installed-using-npm-link)

**UPD**
Can remove symlink from global node_modules.

Find where is global `npm list -g` and remove it

```
   rm -rf `npm list -g | head -1`/node_modules/dependency
```

Comment: So after doing that, `npm link dependency` will still create a symlink with files inside `node_modules`. How is it capable of doing that when I've purged that dependency from my system (supposedly)?

Comment: Maybe link to dependency still exists inside npm.
Should do *npm unlink* from custom library first.