# npx does not find a command specified in the package.jso "bin"

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npx

I have a simple **node Typescript** app whose `package.json` has 2 entries in the `bin` property. The `package.json` file is the following

```
{
    "name": "test-npx-command",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "bin": {
        "test-npx-command": "dist/lib/command.js",
        "second-command": "dist/lib/secondCommand.js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts src/**/**/*.spec.ts",
        "tsc": "tsc --outDir dist",
        "tsc-version": "tsc --version",
        "prepublishOnly": "npm version patch",
        "preversion": "npm run test",
        "version": "npm run tsc && git add -A dist",
        "postversion": "git push"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/chai": "^4.3.4",
        "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
        "@types/node": "^18.15.5",
        "chai": "^4.3.7",
        "mocha": "^10.2.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```

I publish it successfully to https://registry.npmjs.org/ and now I want to execute it using the `npx` command.

I am successful if I try the simple command

```
npx test-npx-command
```

In this case the file `dist/lib/command.js` is actually executed.

But when I try to run the second `bin` entry like this

`npx --package test-npx-command second-command`

I get the following error

**sh: second-command: command not found**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

After you run `npx clear-npx-cache` and then `npx --package test-npx-command second-command` you should see something like `Need to install the following packages: test-npx-command@1.0.6`. I feel like this it's the sure way to know which version of the script you are loading (1.0.6).

[image]

---

Both of your commands seem to work fine for me... I would try clearing your `npx` cache as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510325/how-can-i-clear-the-central-cache-for-npx) and also [making sure you don't have the older versions of this package linked locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094630/how-do-i-uninstall-a-package-installed-using-npm-link), if you used `npm link`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see it is working on your machine. I have tried with the `npx` cache and the `npm link`. Not yet working on my machine. Will try some more.

Comment: @Picci I just added an update to the post.