# npm install after npm link-ing local module causes error: Not found

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-link

package.json of module-A has module-B listed as dependency

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@mynamespace/module-b": "^0.0.1",
```

module B is a local module and is linked successfully from module A with `npm link`. Compiling / running things all goes good and well.

However when I try to install any new module in module A with `npm install something` or just run `npm install` or `npm uninstall something` I always get the error from npm that the local module (which is npm link-ed) is not found.

```
C:\web\module-b>npm install
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @mynamespace/module-b@^0.0.1
```

I checked the `main` property in `package.json` in both modules as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550515/npm-after-npm-link-module-is-not-found). There are several similar questions, but none seem to be exactly this problem or give a solution that works.

Right now I'm manually removing all mentions of linked modules from package.json, then I run npm commands, and than I add them back to package.json

Im using npm 6.1.0

**Edit**: Ah, this might be crucial? @mynamespace/module-b does not exist yet in NPM registry, only locally

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Right now I'm manually removing all mentions of linked modules from package.json, then I run npm commands, and than I add them back to package.json

Unfortunately this is the only way this can work. `npm install` will always search the npm registry if you only specify a version (*i.e* `"@mynamespace/module-b": "^0.0.1",` or `"*"`) so running `npm install` will override what you have in the `node_modules` of your project with what it finds on the npm registry (or throw a 404 in this case).

Assuming you've read [this](https://medium.com/@the1mills/how-to-test-your-npm-module-without-publishing-it-every-5-minutes-1c4cb4b369be#4ad4) article, there is no way to use the `npm link` method and also run `npm install`. For this you'll have to explicitly write the path to the local package in yourmain project's `package.json` (and then change it back when you've published your package).

```
"dependencies": {
  "@mynamespace/module-b": "file:../../module-b",
},
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: it does thanks. I didnt see that article before, so its good to hear a confirmation that there is no other way. I may switch to the relative file path. Tnx!

Comment: I am absolutely baffled that such a basic use case (develop against a local version of a dependency but publish using the published version) seems to be totally unsupported by npm.  Does everybody really just constantly hand-jam changes into their `package.json`?!?

Comment: Good answer, Always do your `npm install` before your `npm link`!

Comment: This actually helped me understand whats going on. I have a package linked but after each npm install, the package throws errors because it apparently uses the one from the npm registry, so I have to npm install, link my package again and even have to go into the package and run npm install there

Answer (score 6):

Npm can do it automatically if you add an "install" script to package.json, which runs right after npm install.

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "npm link <your package>"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

OP here. I've recently [switched to yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/), which is very compatible with npm. Yarn has a thing called [workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) which handles the whole linking issue much better. Havn't had any issues like the above since switching.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `package-lock.json` and then running `npm link <package_name><local_package_path>` fixed the error.