# Node require package and use without prefix

Tags: node.js, package, require

I'm new to Node and to TDD and I'm trying to get my head around how to create tests locally for Codewars JS Katas.

I've got as far as making `var cw = require('kata-test-framework-js');` work by using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18778516/3042018

I can make is work like this: `cw.Test.assertSimilar([1,2,2],[1,2,3]);` but I'd like to be able to use the exact test code from the katas - i.e. without having to prefix everything with `cw.`

Can anyone explain how to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

```
var Test = require('kata-test-framework-js').Test
```

Should do the trick

Comment: It's all about how you name your variables and how you export them. In this case the export is an object **inside** of which there is a `Test`. So if you simply require the package you need to access it. Or you can save a reference during requirement and then use it from there on as a shorthand. It's still a local variable, but with the same name, which makes your life a bit easier. It's a common thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the better explanation @AndreyPopov!

Comment: Thanks for that. It turns out that cw contains several methods: `{ Test: 1,
  describe: [Function],
  it: [Function],
  before: [Function],
  after: [Function] }` Is there a way to use them all without the `cw.`? Maybe I need 5 separate require statements?

Comment: you could require the package and then declare variables for each property

var cw = require('kata-test-framework-js');
var test = cw.Test;
var it = cw.it;
var before = cw.before; and so on