# `npm install` is not installing local package's sub-dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a package (`package-a`) that depends on another package (`package-b`) which is not published to npm but is on my file system. When I run `npm install` from `package-a`, `package-b`'s dependencies are not installed. I have to navigate to `package-b`'s directory and run `npm install` manually. Is there a way to install both packages' dependencies with a single npm command?

Here's my directory structure:

```
/
  ...
  shared/
    ...
    javascript/
      ...
      package-b/
        package.json
  package-a/
    package.json
```

Per [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths), I placed the following in `package-a/package.json`. (I'm using npm 5+)

```
dependencies: {
  package-b: "file:../shared/javascript/package-b",
}
```

When I navigate to `/package-a` and run `npm install`, it installs all of `package-a`'s dependencies like normal and also copies the `package-b` directory to `package-a/node_modules`. This is presumably what lets me type `require('package-b')` instead of `require('../shared/javascript/package-b')` .

However, as I stated before, `package-b`s dependencies are not installed, so if I try to use `package-a`, I get an error when `package-b` is `require`d because it is trying to use dependencies that do not exist locally.

Once again, to solve this, I can navigate to `package-b` and run `npm-install`, but I'm hoping there's a better solution as I may have many such sub packages and I'd like to avoid having to write a shell script to go install all my dependencies if I can do this with an npm command. (perhaps I just did something wrong and `npm install` should be working?)

---

Follow up question: when I run `npm install` from `package-b`'s directory, the packages are installed there, but not in the version of `package-b` that got copied to `/package-a/node_modules` during the first `npm install`, yet everything still works. So now it seems like when I `require('package-b')` it is actually resolving to `/shared/javascript/package-b` and NOT `/package-a/node_modules/package-b`. So what's the point of copying the file in the first place?

---

## Update

It turns out this is a bug in npm 5. It only occurrs when installing from a `package-lock.json` file. ([Github Issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18061))

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59766644/1951947 Using npm pack worked for me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are (probably) not being copied, they're being symbolically linked (symlink). This essentially creates an alias/shortcut that looks like a real directory, but points to another path.

This is how the older `npm link` feature worked. The reason is the code stays "live"; Changes in the linked module are reflected whenever you run the module that's referencing them, meaning you don't have to `npm update` all the time.

Comment: this answers my second question (thanks), but not my first

Comment: Turns out the behavior in question is due to a bug in npm. I'll accept this answer now as it answers my second question.