# Import an external library into a javascript file

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

**UPDATE**

I'have purchased a plugin called [filePicker](https://codecanyon.net/item/filepicker-multi-file-uploader/11557024?s_rank=2) that I want to use in one of my vue.js components.

When I tried to import its libraries this way

```
<script>
    import {filepicker} from '../filepicker';
    import {filepickerdrop} from '../filepicker-drop';
</script>
```

When I run `npm run dev` the 1st time after this, it asked to install this library

```
npm install --save filepicker
```

When I did and tried `npm run dev` the 2nd time, it asked for this

```
npm install --save fs net tls
```

I did and run `npm run dev` a 3rd time, it asked me for this

```
npm install --save fs
```

> This dependency was not found: * fs in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js

**Problem**: It keeps asking me to install this fs library.

These installs have updated my `package.json` to this

```
"dependencies": {
    "filepicker": "^0.2.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "tls": "0.0.1"
}
```

This shows that the library FilePicker has been successfully installed, but the library `fs-security` that it's using is nowhere to be found.

This https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs mentions that "this package name is not currently in use." What does this mean?

LakiGeri, has suggested to locally install the FilePicker according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm). The errors show above that fs is the one who needs to be installed. And I don't have this library to install it.
LakiGeri also suggested to follow the [doc specifications](http://docs.hazzardweb.com/filepicker/2.0/configjs). I'm not even able to import its libraries, so how can even start to work on its configuration.
The third advise was to manually update the dependencies in the `package.json` file. It has already been updated.

I also opened an issue on [npm github repo](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18172). I still have no feedback there.

Comment: Can I add any export in the source file so I can import it?

Comment: do you use npm for handling the js libs?

Comment: yes I do! And I also use Laravel 5.4 on the back end.

Comment: Did you try to install as the doc say? (http://docs.hazzardweb.com/filepicker/2.0/installation). Have you find the js-lib on the https://www.npmjs.com/ ?

Comment: Yes I did. and his demo files work perfectly well because they are inted to be used in a php view or an html page.
The plugin shows that plugins should be imported this way at the end of the <body> tag:
`<script src="{{ mix('js/filepicker.min.js') }}"></script>`
I even did it in the file that includes the Vue component, but the script isn't found in the component.

Comment: when I view the page, I have the following error in the concole : `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs"
at webpackMissingModule (app.js?id=94e27687d7f4327b30c3:99678)
at Object../node_modules/request/lib/har.js (app.js?id=94e27687d7f4327b30c3:99678)`

Comment: I wrote an answer, try that, I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin author has just replied and updated his [sittings](http://docs.hazzardweb.com/filepicker/2.0/laravel#using-with-laravel-mix).
Add the following in `webpack.mix.js` with the following:

```
const path = require('path')

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'filepicker': path.join(__dirname, './resources/assets/js/vendor/filepicker'),
            'filepicker-ui': path.join(__dirname, './resources/assets/js/vendor/filepicker-ui'),
            'filepicker-drop': path.join(__dirname, './resources/assets/js/vendor/filepicker-drop'),
            'filepicker-crop': path.join(__dirname, './resources/assets/js/vendor/filepicker-crop'),
            'filepicker-camera': path.join(__dirname, './resources/assets/js/vendor/filepicker-camera'),
        }
    }
});
```

Now you can import the Filepicker files like this:

```
import 'filepicker';
import 'filepicker-ui';
import 'filepicker-drop';
import 'filepicker-crop';
import 'filepicker-camera';
```

Now it works.

Big thanks to [LakiGeri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349795/lakigeri) for being the only one helping.

Answer (score 1):

I ran some search, and this js lib of the filepicker package is not available on npmjs.com. But you can install the lib from local (check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm)), or you can add the path of the lib in the `package.json` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json). After you imported it, I think you should do nothing, but if it will not work, you have to init this lib as its doc [says](http://docs.hazzardweb.com/filepicker/2.0/configjs).

I hope it helps!

Comment: Not really sure if I am installing it correctly but this is what I did and what I got according to the suggested answer. Should I be in a specific subfolder?
http://imgur.com/a/l75mp

The doc (http://docs.hazzardweb.com/filepicker/2.0/laravel) also suggested to install the package using `composer`. As you can see there already a reference to filePicker in my package.json file.

Does this concerns the issue? https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs It says that this package name is not currently in use. Before installing the package with composer, I had only moment as a dependency in package.json.

Comment: I think when you use the `npm install /path` command, the lib can be anywhere because the npm install will copy the important stuff to node_modules library. But honestly I've never used this before.

Comment: I recommend you to update the question, and not comment the process, becuse that way others can easily find your problem. :)
anyway, what did you try?

Comment: did you try to set the local path of the js? If I understand you correctly, then I have the js lib in local. Is it compatible with npm?

Comment: yes, it did create a link and when I run `npm link filepicker` it only returned this with no error:
`C:\www\projects\myproject\node_modules\filepicker -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\filepicker`

Comment: The plugin contains a package.json file that contains dependencies for glub and elexir. dependencies that have been replaced by webpack and mix in the current version of Laravel

Comment: I can send you the plugin so you can see by yourself. And I accept that you charge me.

Comment: actually I dont know what causes the problem.. maybe this filepicker external lib is not support npm. Have you written for the developers of the filepickers?