# Pass data to custom npm package module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to building custom npm packages and I'm getting lost configuring it with data coming from the application it is using it.

EDIT: This is just an example but the app will have more methods and those fake a and b will be used from many of those methods.

Basically on App I'm requiring my package in this way:

```
var a = 'a';
var b = 'b';
var module = require('module')(a, b);
module.test();
```

My module in his index file has:

```
var a;
var b;

function test() {
  return {
    a: a,
    b: b
  };
}

module.exports = function(_a, _b) {
  a = _a;
  b = _b;

  return {
    test: test
  }
};
```

As you can guess it is not working as I was expecting... How can I pass my custom data to my npm package and be able using that data along my methods?

Comment: This should work as you expected and it does on my machine - did you try to use the name `module` for your module or it just an example? If so, try renaming it to something else as "module" is a predefined module?

Comment: It look like it doesn't receive those 2 variables...

Comment: The code you posted here has no problem.  May be your original code have issues.

Comment: If you guys have no issues maybe you're right and there is another bug in the app. Thanks for the hint and checks, I will take a deeper look.

Comment: Other thing no need to return test function. `module.test()` will do what you are intending to do. just include `module.exports.test = function (){ }` also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shouldnt you use it something like this

```
var a = 'a';
var b = 'b';
var module = require('module');
module.init(a,b);

// do some other code....

module.test();
```

and in your module like this:

```
var _a = null;
var _b = null;
var test = function() {
    return {
        a: _a,
        b: _b
    }
}

var init = function(a, b) {
    _a = a;
    _b = b;
}

module.exports = {
    init,
    test
};
```

Comment: no because I will have several methods using those configuration and I can not pass those configuration every time. I wish to do it at the beginning following the pattern: `require('module')(data);`

Comment: maybe like this, updated? its untested tho, just from mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of a module is absolutely fine but it depends on how you plan on using it!

If you would like to use it as though it were published on the npm-registry then you need to use the process described here: [Installing a local module using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm)

I know that this is an example but for other readers - you shouldn't use the name `module` as this is already in use by Node.

If you are simply using a modular approach to producing a larger app and you want to use the exports of your file, then you require the file by pointing to it. For example, if  this file was called `module.js` and is in the same directory as the script which is requiring it then use:

```
  var myModule = require('./module.js')(a, b);
```

If you have it in another directory then use the normal relative path navigation syntax like `../module.js` if it is up one directory or `./lib/module.js` if it is in a sub-directory called `lib`