# How to use a package from local pc

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, module

In my situation I can't use `npm publish` to publish a package on internet, then `npm install` and use it! Don't want to publish it on remote server like nexus either.
Is there any way to install it from pc cache with `npm install` command?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm

Comment: i want to install it automatically not by giving path

Comment: Copy it to your `node_modules` folder manually?

Comment: Put this in the `package.json`, as shown in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing a local module using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm)

Answer (score 0):

I usually created a folder called `examples` an put into that a file called `test.js` and I declared a variable like this `var myModule = require("../index.js")` and then I declare the functions of my module like : `myModule.substract()` . Also I did read about a module called [NPX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx), I don't use It yet.