# Load an npm package from local directory without copying unnecessary files/folders such as node_modules

Tags: npm, npm-install, npmignore

Let's imagine I have to develop an npm package, **my-package**, which needs to be imported and used by **my-project**.

While developing **my-package** I need to install and use other packages from npm. At the end of the development of **my-package**, I bundle all the relevant files in the *dist* directory. Since I do not want to have all the files in the *node_modules* folder as part of the package published, I specify in *.gitignore* (or *.npmignore*) to exclude *node_modules* folder. So the final structure of the folder of **my-package** looks something like

```
my-package
  dist
    ... // all the code of the package to be distributed
  node_modules
    ... // all the node modules
  src
    ... // all source files
  package.json
  .gitignore
```

Now I publish **my-package** on npm repository and then import it in **my-project**, with the command `npm i my-package`.

As a result of such import, the structure of the directory hosting **my-project** is something like

```
my-project
   ...  // stuff
   node_modules
      my-package
         dist
           ... // all the code of the package to be distributed
         src
           ... // all source files
         package.json
```

As expected, no *node_modules* folder is imported under **my-package** folder.

Since I am the developer of both **my-package** and **my-project**, during development I would like to import **my-package** from the local path with a command which could look like

`npm -i ../my-package`

If I proceed like this, the result I see is that all the files and folders stored under **my-package** directory are copied under the *node_modules* folder of **my-project**, i.e. *.gitignore* (or *.npmignore*) exclusions are not considered. The net result is a structure such as

```
my-project
   ...  // stuff
   node_modules
      my-package
         dist
           ... // all the code of the package to be distributed
         node_modules
           ... // all stuff imported by my-package
         src
           ... // all source files
         package.json
         ...  // any other file under my-package
```

Is there a way to install from local path only the relevant files of **my-package** as it happens if the package is installed from the *npm repository*?

Comment: If your main goal here is to develop _my-package_ in tandem with  _my-project_ then _perhaps_ [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) is a more suitable alternative. Utilizing `npm-link` is explained further in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm#answer-18778516) and fairly good blog [here](http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears). The pitfalls of `npm -i ../mypackage` are noted in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm#comment-36002650).

Comment: added to package.json with  { "my-module": "file:local_modules/my-module"}, detail please refer to https://medium.com/@arnaudrinquin/build-modular-application-with-npm-local-modules-dfc5ff047bcc

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem today. We figure it out by adding to the package.json of the local package

```
“build”: “yarn run clean && yarn build-components && yarn pack”
```

And then to the *project* that is using the local package we added to the dependencies of the package.json

```
“yourpackage”: “file:../your-tgz.tgz”,
```

hope it helps

Note: if you are using yarn you might have problems with the cache.