# Install a downloaded package from GitHub

Tags: github, installation, truffle

I need to download and install Truffle from GitHub.

I have downloaded the ZIP file from the link https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle. But the issue is I don't know how to install this once I have downloaded.

Note: 'npm install -g truffle' for downloading via command line doesn't work for me as I don't have internet access on that machine

Answer (score 0):

Try this from [Installing a local module using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm).

```
npm install /path
```

> you just provide one  argument to npm install, argument should
>   to the local folder instead of the package name

Comment: In such a case, will my command be: npm install C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\truffle-develop\truffle-develop