# $listeners is readonly. $attrs is readonly

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I have an error when using `vue-property-decorator` in my additional library.
[image: _790]

From this stackoverflow answer.
`Vue is being loaded/packed into the bundle by webpack and also loaded externally (not via webpack)`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50932919/5988531

I do something like this in my `main.ts`:

```
import MyIcon from '<my-external-library>/src/components/icon/icon.vue';
Vue.component('my-icon', MyIcon);
```

Then, I use `my-icon` in the project and got an error.

Do you have any comments or suggestions for this?

P.S. I think this is because We need to extend Vue class in `*.vue` file. Can I use property decorators without extending a Vue instance?