# Detect changes of an angular library in the host project

Tags: angular, angular-library

I used the Yeoman generator (https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library) to create an Angular library called my-lib. My angular app is consuming the created library and everything works fine.

The only issue I had is that in the development mode, I have to make frequent changes on my library and execute some commands to rebuild and publish the library to NPM :

```
npm run build
npm publish dist
```

Once I published the library to the NPM registry, I reimport it in my Angular app using the npm install command.

Is there a better way or a shorter path (in the development mode) for detecting changes on the library and reflectiong them to my consuming app ?

ps: The creation of a symlink in the global node_modules directory to the dist directory of the  library:

```
$ cd dist
$ npm link
```

And linking the global library directory to node_modules of the app directory:

```
$ npm link my-lib
```

Does not solve the problem..

Comment: How does symlink not solve the problem? This is how I typically develop with multiple packages, works no problem for me.

Comment: For every change in the lib, you have to run : npm run build, npm link (from the dist folder) and the then npm link lib (from the consuming app).. Is that true ?

Comment: Nope, in the project you want to access the dependency, run `npm link "{Directory of dep}"` and you should be good to code. Live reload probably won't work, but you can just refresh the page.

Comment: Checkout this answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371987/1818637)