# How to executing a script that is located inside a symlink dir?

Tags: javascript, node.js, symlink

I have two directory structure:
The first one, which is my `utils` project is like this

```
mock-utils:   
   app-mock (symlinked to app-mock)
   common
       utils.js
   node_modules
   package.json
   package-lock.json
```

I have another one which is the app-mock which is somewhere locally,

```
app-mock:
  tests
      test.js
```

`test.js` contains the following import, and the entry point for the execution is inside the mock-utils since package.json is located there:

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var shield = require(‘../../common/utils.js’)
```

However, executing `test.js` from `mock-utils` will give the error of
`Error: Cannot find module`

Originally, `app-mock` is inside the `mock-utils` but it have to be separated for git. How do I adjust it so that it would be possible to execute `test.js` while retaining this kind of structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution here:
[Installing a local module using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm)

Please note that due to recent NPM  updates you might need to remove you package-lock.json file for this to work. Avoid running `npm install` during your development because this will recreate the package-lock.json file and npm will try to replace your symlinked package with the real one which, with your current setup, from what i understand, will throw a package not found exception.