# Share JavaScript files among different servers

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a few Node apps, each hosted in a different container (Heroku dyno). All the apps use the same mongo models, so when I change a model, I have to change it for each app. I was wondering if there is a way to share the model files among all my apps.

I thought about hosting the model files in a different container, and then making them available to the apps, but I'm not sure how to do it.

A little more generally speaking, how can I share JavaScript files among different containers / servers? Is that the best approach to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have a repo to contain all mongodb models. whenever update that repo you can trigger a build for depending repos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put your common *model* code into a local npm module as in [Installing a local module using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm) then build and deploy your images as normal.

Comment: I'd like to answer that, but..."Other people?"  I thought this was a code issue.  What do you mean "other people get the updates"?  Maybe your original question should have had more details.  I assume docker is involved here right?  Do you mean to modify a file and then have containers on multiple servers pick up the changes without rebuilding and re-deploying the containers?

Comment: I am sorry if my question wasn't clear. Suppose I am developing a new feature, which requires me to modify a model. Right now, I have to load each of my app projects, change the model and push it, which is kinda annoying. So, I am trying to find a way so that when I make a model change in a particular project and push it, the change is automatically applied to the other apps which use the same model.

Comment: It seems I can crate a npm module, as you suggested, host it on a git repo, and then make it a dependency on all of my app projects.

Comment: Not 100% clear if you are willing to rebuild docker images and redeploy to achieve this, or if you are looking for a run-time solution. I was originally just describing how to set up a code dependency.  I assumed you would rebuild docker images and redeploy apps when you make a change.

Comment: You don't need to host the shared npm module anywhere special.  Just use files relative to your app directories.  If you have `/myproject/myapp1/package.json` and `/myproject/myapp2/package.json` you can create `/myproject/sharedstuff/package.json` and from /myproject/myapp1/ do `npm install ../sharedstuff`  then repeat for myapp2.  The link I provided describes details of how.  Again, assuming you are willing to rebuild and redeploy when you make code changes to your model (shared or otherwise).  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have `/myproject/myapp_x` structure. Each app is in a different project folder. Moreover, some apps are hosted on Heroku and some on AWS. It wasn't me who set them up this way. Given the circumstances, I think I do need to store the npm module in a special place.