# Using a shared node module for common classes

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, npm, node-modules

**Goal**

So I am having a project with this structure:

- ionic-app
- firebase-functions
- shared

The goal is to define common interfaces and classes in the `shared` module.

**Restrictions**

I don't want to upload my code to npm to use it locally and am not planning on uploading the code at all. It should 100% work offline.

While the development process should work offline, the `ionic-app` and `firebase-functions` modules are going to be deployed to firebase (hosting & functions). Therefore, the code from the `shared` module should be available there.

**What I have tried so far**

- I have tried using [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) in typescript, but I have not gotten it close to working
- I tried it with installing it as an npm module like in the second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm)

  - It seems to be working fine at first, but during the build, I get an error like this when running `firebase deploy`:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file lib/index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'shared'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/lib/index.js:5:18)
```

**Question**

Do you have a solution for making a shared module using either typescripts config, or NPM?

Please do not mark this as a duplicate → I have tried any solution I have found on StackOverflow.

**Additional Info**

Config for shared:

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/src/index.js",
  "types": "dist/src/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist/src/**/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "private"
  }
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  }
}
```

Config for functions:

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0",
    "shared": "file:../../shared"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/braintree": "^2.20.0",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}


// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  }
}
```

**Current soution**

I have added a npm script to the shared module, which copies all files (without the index.js) to the other modules. This has the problem, that I check in duplicate code into SCM, and that I need to run that command on every change. Also, the IDE just treats it as different files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Preface:** I'm not too familiar with how Typescript compilation works and how `package.json` in such a module should be defined. This solution, although it works, could be considered a hacky way of achieving the task at hand.

Assuming the following directory structure:

```
project/
  ionic-app/
    package.json
  functions/
    src/
      index.ts
    lib/
      index.js
    package.json
  shared/
    src/
      shared.ts
    lib/
      shared.js
    package.json
```

When deploying a Firebase service, you can attach commands to the [predeploy and postdeploy hooks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#hooks). This is done in `firebase.json` via the properties `predeploy` and `postdeploy` on the desired service. These properties contain an array of sequential commands to run before and after deploying your code respectively. Furthermore, these commands are called with the environment variables `RESOURCE_DIR` (the directory path of `./functions` or `./ionic-app`, whichever is applicable) and `PROJECT_DIR` (the directory path containing `firebase.json`).

Using the `predeploy` array for `functions` inside `firebase.json`, we can copy the shared library's code into the folder that is deployed to the Cloud Functions instance. By doing this, you can simply include the shared code as if it were a library located in a subfolder or you can map it's name using [Typescript's path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in `tsconfig.json` to a named module (so you can use `import { hiThere } from 'shared';`).

The `predeploy` hook definition (uses global install of [`shx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx) for Windows compatibility):

```
// firebase.json
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "shx rm -rf \"$RESOURCE_DIR/src/shared\"", // delete existing files
      "shx cp -R \"$PROJECT_DIR/shared/.\" \"$RESOURCE_DIR/src/shared\"", // copy latest version
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint", // lint & compile
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "ionic-app",
    ...
  }
}
```

Linking the copied library's typescript source to the functions typescript compiler config:

```
// functions/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "shared": ["shared/src"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Associating the module name, "shared", to the copied library's package folder.

```
// functions/package.json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "shared": "file:./src/shared",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The same approach can be used with the hosting folder.

---

Hopefully this inspires someone who is more familiar with Typescript compilation to come up with a cleaner solution that makes use of these hooks.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna), a tool for managing JavaScript (and TypeScript) projects with multiple packages.

### Setup

Assuming that your project has the following directory structure:

```
packages
  ionic-app
    package.json
  firebase-functions
    package.json
  shared
    package.json
```

Make sure to specify the correct access level (`private` and `config/access` keys) in all the modules you don't wish to have published, as well as the `typings` entry in your `shared` module:

Shared:

```
{
  "name": "shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "access": "private"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "typings": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc --project tsconfig.json"
  }
}
```

Ionic-app:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "access": "private"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc --project tsconfig.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "shared": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

With the above changes in place, you can create a root-level `package.json` where you can specify any `devDependencies` that you wish all your project modules to have access to, such as your unit testing framework, tslint, etc.

```
packages
  ionic-app
    package.json
  firebase-functions
    package.json
  shared
    package.json
package.json         // root-level, same as the `packages` dir
```

You can also use this root-level `package.json` to define npm scripts that will invoke the corresponding scripts in your project's modules (via lerna):

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "lerna run compile --stream",
    "postinstall": "lerna bootstrap",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.18.4",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  },
}
```

With that in place, add the lerna config file in your root directory:

```
packages
  ionic-app
    package.json
  firebase-functions
    package.json
  shared
    package.json
package.json
lerna.json
```

with following contents:

```
{
  "lerna": "3.18.4",
  "loglevel": "info",
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Now when you run `npm install` in the root directory, the `postinstall` script defined in your root-level `package.json` will invoke `lerna bootstrap`.

What `lerna bootstrap` does is that it will symlink your `shared` module to `ionic-app/node_modules/shared` and `firebase-functions/node_modules/shared`, so from the point of those two modules, `shared` looks just like any other npm module.

### Compilation

Of course, symlinking the modules is not enough as you still need to compile them from TypeScript to JavaScript.

That's where the root-level `package.json` `compile` script comes into play.

When you run `npm run compile` in your project root, npm will invoke `lerna run compile --stream`, and `lerna run compile --stream` invokes the script called `compile` in each of your modules' `package.json` file.

Since each of your modules now has its own `compile` script, you should can have a `tsonfig.json` file per module. If you don't like the duplication you could get away with a root-level tsconfig, or a combination of a root-level tsconfig and module-level tsconfig files inheriting from the root one.

If you'd like to see how this setup works on a real-world project, have a look at [Serenity/JS](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/tree/2.0) where I've been using it quite extensively.

### Deployment

The nice thing about having the `shared` module symlinked under `node_modules` under `firebase-functions` and `ionic-app`, and your `devDepedencies` under `node_modules` under project root is that if you need to deploy the consumer module anywhere (so the `ionic-app` for example), you could just zip it all up together with its `node_modules` and not worry about having to remove the dev depedencies prior to deployment.

Hope this helps!

Jan

Comment: Intresting! I will definitly check it out and look if this is the right fit.

Comment: this does not work for deploying firebase functions.  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@appName%!f(MISSING)shared - Not found

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, if you are using git to manage your code, is using `git submodule`. Using `git submodule` you are able to include another git repository into your project.

Applied to your use case:

1. Push the current version of your shared-git-repository
2. Use `git submodule add <shared-git-repository-link>` inside your main project(s) to link the shared repository.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: It is actually not a bad idea, but local development and testing is basically gone with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cents on this matter, adding to [samthecodingman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877253/7784904):

I achieved the same results on linux with a simple symlink to the shared module build folder using an additional bootstrap step which would 'replace' the call to *npm install*:

```json
    // ./functions/package.json
    {
    ...
      "scripts": {
        "bootstrap": "npm install && ln -s ../shared/lib shared",
    ...
      "dependencies": {
        "shared": "file:shared",
    ...
    }
```

Remove the symlink from versioning:

```json
    // ./functions/.gitignore
    shared
```

Shared module tsconfig:

```json
    // ./shared/tsconfig.json
    {
    ...
      "dependencies": {
        "outDir": "lib",
        // outputs .d.ts files as well, allowing other modules to point directly
        // to build folder while enjoying type safety
        "declaration": true,
    ...
    }
```

Since the symlink is present *inside the functions folder*, it's contents are copied during firebase deploy.

**Obs.:** The hosting module, on the other hand, can depend on the shared module build folder directly, as long as you are using webpack or similar:

```json
    // ./hosting/package.json
    {
      "dependencies": {
        "shared": "file:../shared/lib",
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the solution is more complex than a single answer and it partly depends on your preference.

**Approach 1: Local copies**

You can use [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to automate the working solution you described already, but IMO it is not very easy to maintain and drastically increases the complexity if at some point another developer comes in.

**Approach 2: Monorepo**

You can create a single repository that contains all three folders and connect them so they behave as a single project. As already answered above, you can use [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna). It requires a bit of a configuration, but once done, those folders will behave as a single project.

**Approach 3: Components**

Treat each one of these folders as a stand-alone component. Take a look at [Bit](https://bit.dev/). It will allow you to set up the folders as smaller parts of a bigger project and you can create a private account that will scope those components only to you. 
Once initially set up, it will allow you to even apply updates to the separate folders and the parent one that uses them will automatically get the updates.

**Approach 4: Packages**

You specifically said that you don't want to use npm, but i want to share it, because I am currently working with a set up as described below and is doing a perfect job for me:

1. Use `npm` or `yarn` to create a package for each folder(you can create scoped packages for both of them so the code will only available to you, if this is your concern).
2. In the parent folder(that uses all of these folders), the created packages are connected as dependencies.
3. I use webpack to bundle all the code, using webpack path aliases in combination with typescript paths.

Works like a charm and when the packages are symlinked for local development it works entirely offline and in my experience - each folder is scalable separately and very easy to maintain.

**Note**

The 'child' packages are already precompiled in my case as they are pretty big and I have created separate tsconfigs for each package, but the beautiful thing is that you can change it easily. In the past I've both used typescript in the module and compiled files, and also raw js files, so the entire thing is very, very versatile.

Hope this helps

*****UPDATE****
To continue on point 4:
I apologize, my bad. Maybe I got it wrong because as far as I know, you cannot symlink a module if it is not uploaded. Nevertheless, here it is:

1. You have a separate npm module, let's use `firebase-functions` for that. You compile it, or use raw ts, depending on your preference.
2. In your parent project add `firebase-functions` as a dependency.
3. In `tsconfig.json`, add `"paths": {"firebase-functions: ['node_modules/firebase-functions']"}`
4. In webpack - `resolve: {extensions: ['ts', 'js'], alias: 'firebase-functions': }`

This way, you reference all your exported functions from the `firebase-functions` module simply by using `import { Something } from 'firebase-functions'`. Webpack and TypeScript will link it to the node modules folder. With this configuration, the parent project will not care if the `firebase-functions` module is written in TypeScript or vanilla javascript.

Once set up, it will work perfectly for production. Then, to link and work offline:

1. Navigate to `firebase-functions` project and write `npm link`. It will create a symlink, local to your machine and will map the link the name you set in package.json.
2. Navigate to parent project and write `npm link firebase-functions`, which will create the symlink and map the dependency of firebase-functions to the folder in you have created it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something. I never said I don't want to use npm. In fact all three of those modules are node modules. I just said, that I don't want to upload my modules to npm. Can you elaborate on that 4th part a bit more - that sounds intresting? maybe provide a code sample?

Comment: I will add another answer, as it will be long and unreadable as a comment

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to upload my code to npm to use it locally and am not planning on uploading the code at all. It should 100% work offline.

All npm modules are installed locally and always work offline, but if you do not want to publish your packages publicly so people can see it, you can install private npm registry.

ProGet is NuGet/Npm Private repository server available for windows which you can use in your private development/production environment to host, access and publish your private packages. Though it is on windows but I am sure there are various alternatives available on linux.

1. Git Submodules is bad idea, it is really an old fashion way to share code which is not versioned like packages are, changing and committing submodules are real pain.
2. Source import folder is also a bad idea, again versioning is issue, because if someone modifies dependent folder in dependent repository, again tracking it is nightmare.
3. Any third party scripted tools to emulate package separation is waste of time as npm already provides range of tools to manage packages so well.

**Here is our build/deployment scenario.**

1. Every private package has `.npmrc` which contains `registry=https://private-npm-repository`.
2. We publish all our private packages onto our privately hosted ProGet repository.
3. Every private package contains dependent private packages on ProGet.
4. Our build server accesses ProGet via npm authentication set by us. Nobody outside our network has access to this repository.
5. Our build server creates npm package with `bundled dependencies` which contains all packages inside `node_modules` and production server never needs to access NPM or private NPM packages as all necessary packages are already bundled.

**Using private npm repository has various advantages,**

1. No need of custom script
2. Fits into node buid/publish pipeline
3. Every private npm package will contain direct link to your private git source control, easy to debug and investigate errors in future
4. Every package is a readonly snapshot, so once published cannot be modified, and while you are making new features, existing code base with older version of dependent packages will not be affected.
5. You can easily make some packages public and move to some other repository in future
6. If your private npm provider software changes, for example you decide to move your code into node's private npm package registry cloud, you will not need to make any changes into your code.

Comment: This might be a solution, but it is unfortunately not for me. Thank you for your time though!

Comment: There is also a local npm repository which is installed as a small node server, https://verdaccio.org/

Answer (score -1):

The tool you are looking for is `npm link`. `npm link` provides symlinks to a local npm package. That way you can link a package and use it in your main project without publishing it to the npm package library.

Applied to your use case:

1. Use `npm link` inside your `shared` package. This will set the symlink destination for future installs.
2. Navigate to your main project(s). Inside your `functions` package and use `npm link shared` to link the shared package and add it to the `node_modules` directory.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html

Comment: As far as I know, npm link is only for testing and does not work if you want to deploy the resulting code (for example my functions).

Comment: I see, you should probably add this requirement to your question.

Comment: It is mentioned in the question already, but I will clarify it.