# Deploying firebase functions with local depencies using firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, yarnpkg

#### Setup

I have a monorepo setup with the following file structure:

```
├── functions
│   ├── src
│   └── package.json
├── shared
|   ├── dist
|   ├── src
|   └── package.json
├── frontend
|    └── ...
└── firebase.json
```

#### Approach 1 (failed)

`./shared` is holding TypeScript classes shared among the `./backend` and `./frontend`. Ideally, I want to reference the shared lib from the `functions/package.json` using a symlink to avoid that I have to re-install after every change to my shared code (where most of the functionality resides).

However, this does not work (neither using `link:`, nor an absolute `file:` path, nor an relative `file:` path)

```
// functions/package.json
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "shared": "file:/home/boern/Desktop/wd/monorepo/shared"
    ...
  }
```

resulting into an error upon `firebase deploy --only functions` (`error Package "shared" refers to a non-existing file '"home/boern/Desktop/wd/monorepo/shared"'`). The library (despite being present in `./functions/node_modules/`) was not transferred to the server?

#### Approach 2 (failed)

Also, setting `"functions": {"ignore": []}` in firebase.json did not help.

#### Approach 4 (works, but lacks requirement a) see Goal)

The only thing that **DID** work, was a proposal by [adevine on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/968#issuecomment-460323113):

```
// functions/package.json
  ...
  "scripts": {
     ...
    "preinstall": "if [ -d ../shared ]; then npm pack ../shared; fi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "shared": "file:./bbshared-1.0.0.tgz"
    ...
  }
```

#### Goal

Can someone point out a way to reference a local library in a way that a) `./functions` always uses an up-to-date version during development and b) deployment using the stock Firebase CLI succeeds (and not, e.g. using [firelink](https://github.com/rxdi/firelink))? Or is this simply not [supported yet](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/653)?

Comment: Tried [this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877253/3068190) yet?

Comment: Please edit that into the question, comments are ephemeral.

Comment: Mono repo are no supported yet, you can use another approachs to deploy a mono repo using for example google cloub build or deploy your functions using google cloud to deploy each function separately.

Comment: Hey mate, did you find any solution ?

Comment: Hey @Titou, unfortunately not. I went up zipping my shared library and copying it to the functions folder. Involves manual effort (i.e. increasing the version) every time.

Comment: I'm turning crazy with this problem ! Even when I "npm pack" my local dependency, I change my package.json to link to ./core.1.0.0.tgz for example, install using npm i, build using tsc and then deploy using firebase deploy --only functions, it's not working...

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'core/src/services/event'

Comment: I'll post my crappy solution next week !

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, monorepos are indeed not supported yet by the Firebase tools deploy command / pipeline.

I have developed [a generic solution](https://github.com/0x80/isolate-package) and wrote an article about it. Below is an
excerpt with the relevant parts, but here is a link to the [full
article](https://thijs-koerselman.medium.com/deploy-to-firebase-without-the-hacks-e685de39025e)
in case you are interested.

> ### The problem with Firebase
>
> When deploying to Firebase it wants to upload a folder just like a
> traditional single package repository, containing the source files
> together with a manifest file declaring its external dependencies.
> After receiving the files in its cloud deployment pipeline, it then
> detects the package manager and runs an install and build.
>
> In a monorepo, and especially a private one, your Firebase code
> typically depend on one or more shared packages from the same
> repository, for which you have no desire to publish them anywhere.
>
> Once Firebase tries to look up those dependencies in the cloud they
> can not be found and deployment fails.
>
> ### Hacking your way out
>
> #### Using a bundler
>
> In order to solve this you could try to use a bundler like Webpack to
> combine your Firebase code with the shared packages code and then
> remove those packages from the package.json manifest that is being
> sent to Firebase, so it doesn’t know these packages even existed.
>
> Unfortunately, this strategy quickly becomes problematic…
>
> If the shared packages themselves do not bundle all of their
> dependencies in their output, Firebase doesn’t know what the shared
> code depends on, because you are not including or installing those
> manifests.
>
> You could try to bundle everything then, but if your shared package
> depends on things your Firebase package also depends on, you now have
> one part of your code running an internally bundled copy of a
> dependency and the other part using that same dependency from a
> different location installed by the package manager.
>
> Also, some libraries really don’t like to be bundled, and in my
> experience that includes the Firebase and Google client libraries. You
> will quickly find yourself trying to externalize things via the
> bundler settings in order get thing to work.
>
> And even if you managed to make all this work, you are probably
> creating large bundles which could then lead to problems with the
> cold-start times of your cloud functions.
>
> Not exactly a reliable or scalable solution.
>
> #### Packing and linking local dependencies
>
> An arguably more elegant approach involves packing the local
> dependencies into a tarball (similar to how a package would be
> published to NPM), and copying the results to the build output before
> linking them in an altered manifest file.
>
> This could work quite nicely, as it basically resembles how your
> Firebase code would have worked if these packages were installed from
> an external domain.
>
> Whether you’re doing this manually, or write a shell script to handle
> things, it still feels very cumbersome and fragile to me, but I think
> it is a viable workaround if your local dependencies are simple.
>
> However, this approach quickly becomes hairy once you have shared
> packages depending on other shared packages, because then you’ll have
> have multiple levels of things to pack and adapt.
>
> ### A solution
>
> I spent a lot of hours trying out the different workarounds, before I
> realized what a convenient solution could look like. Initially, I was
> going for something specific to PNPM, but while working on it I realized that
> support for other package managers shouldn't be that difficult.
>
> It feels good to be able to contribute something useful to the
> community, and so I have created
> [isolate-package](https://github.com/0x80/isolate-package). The name
> is generic because it doesn’t contain anything specific to Firebase,
> although I currently don’t know of any other use-cases for isolated
> output.
>
> It takes a similar approach to what is described earlier in packing
> and linking dependencies, but does so in a more sophisticated way. It
> is designed to handle different setups and package managers and it
> completely hides the complexity from the user.
>
> The isolate binary it exposes can simply be added to the Firebase
> predeploy hook, and that’s pretty much it!
>
> This also allows you to deploy to Firebase from multiple different
> packages and keep the configuration co-located instead of littering
> the monorepo root directory.
>
> It should be zero-config for the vast majority of use-cases, and is
> designed to be compatible with all package managers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my workaround to make approach 4 work:

```sh
rm -rf ./node_modules
yarn cache clean # THIS IS IMPORTANT
yarn install
```

Run this from the `./functions` folder