# How to use pnpm workspace protocol and deploy Firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, pnpm, file-uri, pnpm-workspace

I have a pnpm monorepo and I use the `workspace:` protocol to add my `shared` folder as a local package.

The `workspace:` protocol is not recognized by Firebase when deploying functions and I have the following error:

```
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:../shared
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-03-19T21_44_16_828Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: b0ba1f57
```

How do I deploy my Firebase functions using pnpm workspace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying firebase functions with local depencies using firebase CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239777/deploying-firebase-functions-with-local-depencies-using-firebase-cli)

Answer (score 4):

This question is basically a duplicate of [Deploying firebase functions with local depencies using firebase CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239777/deploying-firebase-functions-with-local-depencies-using-firebase-cli/76207027?noredirect=1#comment134390781_76207027)

The PNPM workspace protocol is not supported, because the Firebase deploy command doesn't understand monorepos in general. You would face the same problem with Yarn or NPM based monorepos.

I have developed a generic solution for this and wrote an article about it. Below is an
excerpt so that you have the full answer, but here is a link to the [full
article](https://thijs-koerselman.medium.com/deploy-to-firebase-without-the-hacks-e685de39025e)

> ### The problem with Firebase
>
> When deploying to Firebase it wants to upload a folder just like a
> traditional single package repository, containing the source files
> together with a manifest file declaring its external dependencies.
> After receiving the files in its cloud deployment pipeline, it then
> detects the package manager and runs an install and build.
>
> In a monorepo, and especially a private one, your Firebase code
> typically depend on one or more shared packages from the same
> repository, for which you have no desire to publish them anywhere.
>
> Once Firebase tries to look up those dependencies in the cloud they
> can not be found and deployment fails.
>
> ### Hacking your way out
>
> #### Using a bundler
>
> In order to solve this you could try to use a bundler like Webpack to
> combine your Firebase code with the shared packages code and then
> remove those packages from the package.json manifest that is being
> sent to Firebase, so it doesn’t know these packages even existed.
>
> Unfortunately, this strategy quickly becomes problematic…
>
> If the shared packages themselves do not bundle all of their
> dependencies in their output, Firebase doesn’t know what the shared
> code depends on, because you are not including or installing those
> manifests.
>
> You could try to bundle everything then, but if your shared package
> depends on things your Firebase package also depends on, you now have
> one part of your code running an internally bundled copy of a
> dependency and the other part using that same dependency from a
> different location installed by the package manager.
>
> Also, some libraries really don’t like to be bundled, and in my
> experience that includes the Firebase and Google client libraries. You
> will quickly find yourself trying to externalize things via the
> bundler settings in order get thing to work.
>
> And even if you managed to make all this work, you are probably
> creating large bundles which could then lead to problems with the
> cold-start times of your cloud functions.
>
> Not exactly a reliable or scalable solution.
>
> #### Packing and linking local dependencies
>
> An arguably more elegant approach involves packing the local
> dependencies into a tarball (similar to how a package would be
> published to NPM), and copying the results to the build output before
> linking them in an altered manifest file.
>
> This could work quite nicely, as it basically resembles how your
> Firebase code would have worked if these packages were installed from
> an external domain.
>
> Whether you’re doing this manually, or write a shell script to handle
> things, it still feels very cumbersome and fragile to me, but I think
> it is a viable workaround if your local dependencies are simple.
>
> However, this approach quickly becomes hairy once you have shared
> packages depending on other shared packages, because then you’ll have
> have multiple levels of things to pack and adapt.
>
> ### My solution
>
> I have created
> [isolate-package](https://github.com/0x80/isolate-package). The name
> is generic because it doesn’t contain anything specific to Firebase,
> although I currently don’t know of any other use-cases for isolated
> output.
>
> It takes a similar approach to what is described earlier in packing
> and linking dependencies, but does so in a more sophisticated way. It
> is designed to handle different setups and package managers and it
> completely hides the complexity from the user.
>
> The isolate binary it exposes can simply be added to the Firebase
> predeploy hook, and that’s pretty much it!
>
> This also allows you to deploy to Firebase from multiple different
> packages and keep the configuration co-located instead of littering
> the monorepo root directory.
>
> It should be zero-config for the vast majority of use-cases, and is
> designed to be compatible with all package managers.

Answer (score 1):

1. `functions/package.json`

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "functions",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc --watch",
    "build": "tsc",
    "pre-deploy": "node pre-deploy.js",
    "post-deploy": "node post-deploy.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "4.2.1",
    "shared": "workspace:../shared"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18",
    "pnpm": "7"
  }
}
```

2. `functions/pre-deploy.js`

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { existsSync, copyFileSync, readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs')

const packagePath = './package.json'
const packageCopyPath = './package-copy.json'
const pnpmWorkspaceRegex = /workspace:/gi

// Abort if "package-copy.json" exists
if (existsSync(packageCopyPath)) {
  console.error(`"${packageCopyPath}" exists, previous deployment probably failed.`)
  return
}

// Copy "package.json" file
copyFileSync(packagePath, packageCopyPath)

// Read "package.json" file and replace "workspace:" to "file:" protocol
const packageBuffer = readFileSync(packagePath)
const packageContent = packageBuffer.toString()
const packageNewContent = packageContent.replace(pnpmWorkspaceRegex, 'file:')

writeFileSync(packagePath, packageNewContent)
```

3. `functions/post-deploy.js`

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { rmSync, renameSync } = require('fs')

const packagePath = './package.json'
const packageCopyPath = './package-copy.json'

// Restore original "package.json" file with "workspace:" protocol
rmSync(packagePath)
renameSync(packageCopyPath, packagePath)
```

4. `firebase.json`

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "codebase": "default",
    "predeploy": [
      "pnpm --filter functions run build",
      "pnpm --filter functions run pre-deploy"
    ],
    "postdeploy": [
      "pnpm --filter functions run post-deploy"
    ],
    "ignore": [
      ".git",
      "node_modules",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log"
    ]
  }
}
```

The steps above assume that the `pnpm-workspace.yaml` file contains the following information:

```yaml
packages:
  - 'functions'
  - 'shared'
```

Comment: ℹ️ https://stackoverflow.com/a/75790114/10531083

Comment: But you cannot use a file reference outside of the functions directory

Comment: Finally, I create symbolic links with the "fs-extra" package. A script is run with npm's "prepare" hook on each installation/deployment to update the symbolic links.

Comment: I ended up going with `tsup` and a `pre` and `postdeploy` remove the local dependency from my package.json during deploy and add it back afterwards, since i can bundle it together with my `dist/index.js` using `tsup`