# Could not install from "./shared" as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to deploy my firebase functions but I'm encountering the error. I have a local dependency which I pack with my functions and it works fine on my local environment but I can't deploy it on cloud. It was working fine months ago but now I can't find the issue. Can someone please help me out on this? I have tried all my luck by deleting node_modules from both shared and function folder and tried reinstalling but deployment still causes the issue.

- NodeJS version 12.13.0
- NPM 6
- firebase-tool 7.16.1

Here is my `package.json` file for functions:

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "pack:loanshub-shared": "npm pack file:../shared",
    "update-models": "npm run pack:loanshub-shared && npm install loanshub-shared -force",
    "build": "tsc && npm run pack:loanshub-shared",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "tslint-check": "tslint-config-prettier-check ./tslint.json",
    "deploy-backend": "firebase deploy --only functions,firestore:rules,storage:rules,database:rules && firebase use preview",
    "deploy:preview": "firebase use preview && npm run deploy-backend",
    "deploy:production": "firebase use production && npm run deploy-backend",
    "emulate": "firebase use preview && npm run get-config && firebase functions:shell && firebase emulators:exec \"./tests/test.sh\"",
    "get-config": "firebase use preview && firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register tests/**/**.spec.ts"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.0.6",
    "firebase": "^7.16.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.0",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "loanshub-shared": "file:loanshub-shared-1.0.0/package",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@firebase/testing": "^0.20.11",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.14",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.6",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.5",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.46",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1",
    "mocha-typescript": "^1.1.17",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried running `npm run deploy:preview` but I receive the following error everytime I try to deploy it

```
!  functions[syncApplication(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: > functions@ build /workspace
> tsc && npm run pack:loanshub-shared


> functions@ pack:loanshub-shared /workspace
> npm pack file:../shared

npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "../shared" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-12-20T12_05_39_746Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ pack:loanshub-shared: `npm pack file:../shared`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ pack:loanshub-shared script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-12-20T12_05_39_767Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc && npm run pack:loanshub-shared`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-12-20T12_05_39_780Z-debug.log; Error ID: 1a2262f3
```

I tried updating function@latest but that also didn't work. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Only the contents of your `functions` directory are deployed to Cloud Functions. You can't use `../shared` to navigate up to your Firebase project directory as it is not deployed with your functions source code. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58632138/3068190) covers various strategies for overcoming this.