# Best practice to import a vue instance inside another

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, gitlab

This is the context: I have two separate projects that have a common layer of components.

Both projects are on gitlab on separate repos and both have gitlab CI pipelines that helps us with deploy.

`In project 1 (the builder)` we have a layer of components that we can rearrange and reposition.

`In project 2` we use the same layer to display those components in their respective position / order as we set it on builder.

Right now, when we do modifications on those components, we just copy/paste them over builder project so we can ensure the exact same thing is shown on both sides.

I would like to take that layer of components and move it outside and import it in those 2 projects. I just don't know where i should start to do this and if this is possible to work with current CI flow we have

Something like:

```html
<!-- ON THE BUILDER -->
<div class="builder">
  <div class="other-stuff"></div>
  <components-layer>
    <component-one :editable="true" />
    <component-two :editable="true" />
    <component-three :editable="true" />
  </components-layer>
</div>


<!-- ON THE CLIENT VIEW -->
<div class="client-view">
  <div class="bla-bla-stuff"></div>
  <components-layer>
    <component-one />
    <component-two />
    <component-three />
  </components-layer>
</div>
```

Comment: This common component, did you install it as a package?

Comment: no, nothing is installed. everything is written by us

Comment: Then you probably should. Given it's imported in multiple projects. In other words, do a repo for this shared component and have the projects (builder & client) install and import it. And let your package manager of choice handle the versions.

Comment: @YomS. so i should publish it on npm? is there any other solution where we don't publish publicly this package (maybe without payment)?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a public package, you could actually install a private package. I don't personally use GitLab, but [this doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#installing-a-package) should get you started.

Comment: If you don't need the package be on the cloud, you could also [install it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371987/3634538).