# Making a local Javascript library - Do I have to publish an NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have some javascript utility functions that I would like to be able put in a central folder and reference from different projects.

It seems I cant import functions from outside the src file in of my project.

Do I have to publish an NPM package?
Do I have to duplicate the code in each project?

Am using javascript/node + vscode.

thanks

Comment: No, you absolutely do not have to publish to npm to use a library module in multiple projects. Read the documentation of your dependency management tool. If you're not using one, you're not using npm anyway.

Comment: Hi Bergi, I do certainly use NPM to install various public NPM packages.  And I do have a package.json file as part of my project.  I dont have another dependency management tool.  What do you recommend?

Comment: If you're using `npm` (which you had not stated in your question), see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15806241/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/8088795/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/14381898/1048572 etc

Comment: Thank you, Bergi.  Sorry if I wasnt clear.  The references you provided https://stackoverflow.com/q/15806241/1048572 answered my question.  I'll add a little more detail below in an answer

Answer (score 4):

To create a local (unpublished) library package

1. Create a 'my-library' folder. Include source code, exporting any desired functions.  Folder must include the 'package.json' file generated by `npm init`
2. `cd` into the folder of the project that needs to *use* your library. Run `npm install --save  local/path/to/my-library`.
   The `--save` will add the package to your dependencies in the project's package.json file, as it does with 3rd party published packages.  It will also add a copy of the source code to the node modules folder of the project, as always.
3. import/require the package as you would normally, from any project.  For example
   `import { myFunction } from "my-library"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) for dividing projects into multiple packages locally. It uses the same node_modules and can be deployed to NPM anytime.