# Npm install local directory on windows out-of-the-box

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I have a package which resides in a subfolder of another package (or anywhere locally), and the parent package now needs to install it:

```
main
 ├──node_modules
 ├──otherProject
 │   ├──node_modules
 │   ├──index.js
 │   └──package.json
 ├──package.json
 └──something.anything
```

The files (apart from `node_modules` and other common items) are from version control. Is there a way to do this on windows 7/8/10 without elevated permissions, that works "out of the box"?

On linux this would be a simple `npm install ./otherProject`.

While not too relevant, i'll add that this is a custom eslint plugin. Maybe someone has a tip that solves the specific situation, but isn't generalizable.

---

A short summary of the issues:

- To create symlinks on windows, the process needs administrator permissions, or [developer mode](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/) on windows 10. I'd not count either as "out of the box", a build needing administrator or special OS-flags is a non-solution. This means neither `npm install <folder>` nor `npm link` work, as both create symlinks.
- An alternative is creating a tarball, and installing that. First of all, this introduces an unnecessary copy, which complicates making changes to the package. Secondly, this tarball needs to be created, before installation, but `preinstall` for mythical reasons is still not done first. Updating fails, as it tries to resolve the file, before `preinstall` generated it.

I don't see any of the solutions in e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm) to apply. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62921053/12435589) helped with the tarball approach, which is also now stuck. I hope i am just misunderstanding something, or making a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think is a bad practice to reference a module from another folder to production.

I recommend you have a different folder for each project:

```
main
 ├──mainProject
 │   ├──node_modules
 │   ├──package.json
 │   └──something.anything
 ├──otherProject
 │   ├──node_modules
 │   ├──index.js
 │   └──package.json
 └──otherProject-1.0.0.tgz // This file is created by node...
```

So first you package the other project and install it in your main project

```
main> npm pack otherProject
main> cd mainProject
main\mainProject> npm install --save ../otherProject-1.0.0.tgz
```

You would have more control and your solution will be cleaner.

**NOTE:** If you don't change the version in package.json in `otherProject` when you make any change and pack it you will have the previous version.

In case you want to keep the version in `package.json` you could clean the cache of npm with:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Thanks, but a few questions: What's the reason to not have `otherProject` as a subfolder? The described approach works either way. Then, using an intermediate tarball  manually is possible, but if the project is obtained from git (or a similar source), a `npm i` will fail, as `otherProject-1.0.0.tgz` won't exist (it's a generated file, not in git). As mentioned, `preinstall` isn't early enough to work here as far as i can see. My current plan is attaching a rather complex build-script to a git-hook (needs to hash files and more), but i'd have much preferred not breaking `npm i`.

Comment: PS: a few mentions, which shouldn't be too important, but might give more context: the output from the entire project is a website, the package not intended for use as a dependency. As mentioned on the side in the question, `otherProject` is a custom eslint-plugin, and the "main project" here is eslint plus plugins, for the eslint-extension in vscode. It's a setup to lint other projects contained in `main`. From what i found, eslint plugins are best added as a package (sadly the way eslint resolves them). I also thought about a proxy package, which just re-exports the plugin from its path.