# How to force npm not to create symbolic link to local package?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I downloaded local copy of npm package and extracted it on desktop.
Then I used `npm install /directory/` to install it.

What I noticed is that when I remove desktop directory, app says it can't find installed module. After further investigation I noticed that package is in `node_modules` but it has arrow next to it and it says "symbolic link" which I suppose is a link to desktop directory with this package.

How do I install it independently so that it is fully contained in node_modules allowing me to remove desktop copy?

Comment: How did you download the "local copy"? Is it something not on the online repository?

Comment: It is a paid javascript library and it's not hosted on any site. You get direct download link to it. It is an npm package though. It has `package.lock` file in it, javascript code and ts type definitions.

Comment: Do they have documentation on how to install it (probably in their README or somewhere), then?

Comment: Okay you get your answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm#comment102170132_8089029

Comment: This doesn't resolve my issue. I resolved it other way and posted below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out you can use

```
npm pack /path/to/package
```

This will cause npm to pack package into a `.tgz` file.
Then you can install it from a `.tgz` file using a standard

```
npm install /path/to/file.tgz
```

This will force npm to create a local copy in `node_modules` without symbolic link