# I cannot install an npm package which is a local folder in a Docker image

Tags: docker, npm

Adding other packages to the package.json works well. However installing a local package which is a folder cannot.

Part of my Dockerfile is the following:

```
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN rm -rf node_modules

COPY . .

RUN npm i
RUN npm i ./textwrap-pkg  // <--- it is well executed ! if I make a typo it would raise an error.
```

So as you can see the folder `textwrap-pkg` is well copied part of `COPY . .` (I also logged into the image and could see). What I cannot find, and which is the problem, is the folder of the package in `node_modules` inside the Docker image.

The dependency in `package.json` is fine as it works on the host machine:

`"textwrap": "file:./textwrap-pkg"`

note: I tried removing volumes and images like [suggested](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/mash-local/4.3.0/doc/html/docker/GUID-BD850566-5B79-4915-987E-430FC38DAAE4.html).

### Edit

After a bit of investigations, I found out the source of the problem!

`node_modules# ls -l textwrap-wasm-demo`

> textwrap-wasm-demo -> ../textwrap/examples/wasm/pkg

Isn't this awesome? It's a link. I followed with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69882320/15313684), now I have files well present but still it does not work!

Comment: Could you please share what's the build output? error?

Comment: These is no issue in the build (Docker / npm i) process. It does not even raise an error (it does when I make a typo in the path, so).
the error appears at runtime by Node when importing the dependency (because not installed correctly / not in node_modules)
`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '/usr/src/app/node_modules/textwrap-wasm-demo/' imported from /usr/src/app/text.js`

Comment: could you please add text.js file to the question description?

Comment: there is nothing special in it? I'm just import the package with its name : `import { draw_wrapped_text, WasmOptions, WasmPenalties } from "textwrap-wasm-demo";`

Comment: Could you clarify your solution? You've said that you found the source of the problem, but that it still does not work - I am not clear if you have solved your problem. If you have, would you write an answer proper below?