# How do I check that my npm package is installable on all the Node versions and platforms I want to support?

Tags: npm, github-actions

I publish an npm package that uses C++ code using [nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan). How can I double check that my package can be installed/imported on Linux, macOS and Windows with Node 14+ after I run `npm publish`?

Comment: Could you please share your workflow?

Comment: @AndriiBodnar https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/tree/master/.github/workflows

Comment: The first thoughts - having separate jobs (ubuntu, macos, windows) that will install your package as a local module https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm

and then a separate job to publish if all the previous jobs were successful.