# npm install is not creating a symlink for local folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to install a local library which works, but it isn't creating a symlink, its is copying the contents of the folder into `node_modules` instead.

I have tried setting up the path both of these ways and still it just copy and pastes:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@org/my-library": "../library/dist/component-library"
    "@org/my-library": "file:../library/dist/component-library"
  }
}
```

I am running the install command, and I have tried with the following flags as well:

```bash
npm i
npm i --force
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

But still it just copies and pastes the contents. I know this, because I rebuild the library by adding things or removing things yet the file within `node_modules` still has the old code (with or without the added/removed lines).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing a local module using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm)

Comment: I've answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75800005/274312